# Getting single value from server and saving to sharedpreferences

Tags: string, sharedpreferences, json

I am trying to get this`{"status": [{"RegistrationID":"4"}]}`
value from server and save that value in sharedpreferences but that is throwing nullpointerexception this is the code i am trying...

```
        JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject obj = o.optJSONObject("status");
        String uid = obj.optString("RegistrationID");
        Log.e("RegistrationID", uid);
        AvailableItems  set = new AvailableItems();

        set.sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String value = set.sp.getString("RegistrationID", uid);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = set.sp.edit();
        editor.putString("first", value);
        editor.commit();
```

Exception is showing in this line `String uid = obj.optString("RegistrationID");'

Comment: @hardik vyas now check that....

Comment: what type of variable is 'result' ? does it a string or any other format

Comment: @ Ragu Swaminathan yes result is string type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting array in the resulting string. But in your code you are fetching it as an JsonObject. "RegistrationID" comes in a Array.
Try the below code.

```
try {
      JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result);
      JSONArray obj = o.getJSONArray("status");
      JSONObject jsonobj = obj.getJSONObject(0);
      Log.e("RegistrationID", jsonobj.getString("RegistrationID"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Happy coding..!!

Comment: that the answer Ragu but now there is another issue in the line AvailableItems  set = new AvailableItems(); and this is showing in logcat   RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: that is another question for me. Did this one works for you ? If yes kindly accept it.

Comment: and now please suggest any solution for that problem also i am new in android

Comment: can you post is as a separate issue. Because as per as SO, one question per answer. If you want to ask another question post it as a different one. Sorry for that..

Comment: please check i have post a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173611/runtimeexception-when-trying-to-store-value-fetched-from-server-to-sharedprefere